# Material does not apply to array

Tags: materials, modifiers

Sorry if this is a silly question but I am terribly new to blender. I have created a material and applied it to a sphere. I then added an array modifier. I expected the material to apply to the entire array, but it only applies in material view and in render view to the original sphere. All of the tutorial videos I have watched state that the material automatically transfers to the entire array, so I am at a loss.[image]

Comment: yes it should, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello :). This is probably a Volumetrics limitation in Eevee. Switch to Cycles or plug your nodes into the Surface input and it should work.

Comment: Switching to cycles or surface does make the material appear on all objects of the array, but it no longer has the look that I wanted

Comment: You are asking about issues with shaders but failed to post your node tree. If we are to diagnose the issue, you should properly post the full material setup, without it it will be hard to guess anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example Blender has basicly drawn a line. Everything on one side is assigned the number 0, everything on the other the number 1. Your ColorRamp is using black for 0 and red for 1.

You need a different node setup or you can create instances instead of using the array modifier by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

[image: texture coordinate]

Comment: Thanks! At least now I know where to look for a different solution. Sadly, creating instances isn't a good option for what I require.

Answer (score 1):

**Use generated coords, drive the scale.**

*Nodes aren't particularly my strong point.  Looking at the question setup can make minor alterations to get the effect of gradient across array*

- change the texture to generated (modified)

[image]

- and drive the scale with the array count of object.

[image]

The driver

[image]